# How To Pass php Array To jplayer

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, jplayer

Good Afternoon All

I have an array created in php named $tracks[] populated with links to mp3 files

The jplayer is called via an include statement in the main page: include 'player_script.php';

I am able to play a single track from the first element of the array but not the subsequent tracks

```
var allsongs = <?php echo json_encode($href); ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Player",
                mp3: allsongs,
            }).jPlayer("play");

            ;
        },
        swfPath: "/player/dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });
});
```

The code above does not loop so it's not going to populate the list

I'd like to know how to create a playlist for jplayer with the array data to fully populate the list

I created the arrays in php using loops. Is there a similar way to extract the data for the list in javascript to work with jplayer?

Thanks in advance~

Comment: Did you check this? http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

Comment: I did and it was clear as mud hence the question here... In pouring over the code I still don't see how to pull values from a json array and populate the playlist...

Comment: Seems like it's only possible if you use their Playlist plugin, in which you can pass an object for each song.

Comment: I'd seen people trying to push array data in to the json. 

I can get the array length from this var length = allsongs.length;

Where allsongs is the json containing the php array data.   

I'm going to try adding tracks to the playlist using a loop.

Thanks....!

Comment: Got it! I was able to loop and add the songs to the playlist. Now, because of how I got this to work, the autoplay won't ... Suggestions?